# Assert and should not working when test by Mocha

Tags: mysql, callback, mocha.js

Here is the function I want to test. It'll get database from mysql

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'toor',
  database : 'DB'
});
exports.findById = function(id, callback){
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    var row;
    var query = connection.query( "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = '" + id + "'", function(err, rows) {
       connection.release();
       callback(null,rows[0]);
     });
     console.log(query.sql);
  });
}
```

I do the manual test for this function. The value of rows[0] should be like this

```
var user = {
        id: 1,
        username: 'test',
        password: '123',
        name: 'test user',
        phone: '01699924568'
      }
```

So this is the test I wrote for it

```
var User = require('../Lib/users.js');
var assert = require('assert');
var should = require('should');
describe('Test User Class', function() {
  describe('Test case 1: Load user with id from database', function() {
    it('should return user with id = 1 in database', function() {
      User.findById(1, function(error, rows){
        rows.id.should.be.equal(2)
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This test should cause an error because the returned id is 1 (not 2). However it doesn't happen as expecting, the test passed.
I really get mad at this error. I tried many ways such as let `exports.findById` function return rows[0] but it returned undefined although rows[0] has its value (I test by console log it)
Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `mocha` in some way that the test is asynchronous.

Your `findById` function doesn't block the execution in the thread to perform the action but it is getting a callback: that means it is an asynchronous function.

In `mocha` to notify that you have an async test you have two options:

- Use the `done` callback
- Return a Promise if you have one

In your case, you don't have any Promise, so you have to use the formaer way.

```
var User = require('../Lib/users.js');
var assert = require('assert');
var should = require('should');
describe('Test User Class', function() {
  describe('Test case 1: Load user with id from database', function() {
    it('should return user with id = 1 in database', function( done ) {
      User.findById(1, function(error, rows){
        rows.id.should.be.equal(2);
        // now tell mocha you're done with the test
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes. The problem was solved. I finally could write the test